# slow data tranfer speed between Linux Machine and SMB shared folder on synology NAS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nas, samba

I have Synology NAS connected to my LAN. The Router, NAS and cables are Gigabit speed capable. I have also checked line speed using `ethtool eth0` see details below

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                           drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

Whenever I copy files from my Kubuntu 20.04 laptop using default file manager (Dolphin) to SMB shared folder on NAS I only get 17-18 MiB/s speed. I have tested using Ethernet cable as well as WiFi.

This seems to be really slow.

What can I do to improve the speed? Any ideas on how to debug where the bottleneck is, will be really appreciated?

**Edit:**

to provide more context, I have SHR array in Synology which has two WD Red NAS drives (CMR) directly connected to motherboard via SATA connectors. The laptop from where I copy the files has 512 GB Samsung EVO 850 SSD drive.

PS. I have also tested copying data from external USB 3 HDD connected to NAS directly, and it gives me average of 130 MiB/s for same files. so I guess issue seems to be with SMB software [configs] in Kubuntu 20.04 or Synology NAS

Comment: is the disk mounted inside the NAS, or attached to it via USB? What type of disk are you writing to (preferably a model number). Generally, these issues are about disk IO rather than network. 17-30MB/s is what I would associate with a USB2 connected disk. USB3 will be more like 45MB/s.

Comment: Hi @frank-thomas ,  I have SHR array in Synology which has two WD Red NAS drives directly connected via SATA. The laptop from where I copy the files from has Samsung EVO 850 SSD drive. I have also tested copying data from external USB 3 HDD connected to NAS directly and it gives me average of 130 MiB/s for same files. so I guess issue seems to be with SMB

Comment: Try manually mounting the share on Linux (`mount -t cifs …`).

Comment: Is Ubuntu fully updated?

Comment: @harrymc i have Kubuntu and its fully updated

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Try another ethernet cable. (2) Try configuring samba with : `socket options = TCP_NODELAY` and `aio read size = 0`. (3) On Windows try `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled`. (4) Try [Samba Optimizations](https://calomel.org/samba_optimize.html).